# Cannot get username in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-boot-jpa

The problem is: When I use JpaRepository and use a method to get the user by username like the code below:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select * from users where username = :name", nativeQuery = true)
    User findUserByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

This is the entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "joined_date", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date joinedDate;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "bio")
    private String bio;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
}
```

And this is the controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/u")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;
    ....

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUsernameAndPasswordByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        User user = repo.findUserByName(name);

        if(user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is the entire data of JSON while getting all user from DB:

[image]

And when I get user from name(the url: `localhost/u/{username}`):

[image]

I assure that the name entered from the URL is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two methods with the same mapping

```
1 - getUsernameAndPasswordByName(@PathVariable("name") String name)
@GetMapping("/{name}")
2 - getUserById(@PathVariable("id") int id)
@GetMapping("/{id}")
```

and this is ambiguous for spring; 
just change one of mappings to something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/find-by-id/{id}")
```

Comment: so I have the url like: `/u/find-by-id/{id}` and /u/{name}` right?

Comment: @HarryCoder Yes; exactly

Answer (score 2):

you have duplicate mappings in your `UserController` for the path `/u/{name}`. `getUserById` and `getUsernameAndPasswordByName` have same endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

The error states that you have mapped two RestController methods with similar path:

`getUsernameAndPasswordByName` and `getUserById`.

Try have different `@GetMapping` values, for example: `@GetMapping("/name/{name}"), @GetMapping("/id/{id}")`.

Answer (score 2):

Spring is not able to distinguish between `getUsernameAndPasswordByName(String)` and `getUserById(Integer)` because your mapping is ambiguous.

Try to use a query parameter for the `getUsernameAndPasswordByName(String)` method, it will be more appropriate like -

```
    getUsernameAndPasswordByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) 

    //and

    getUserById(@PathVariable("id") int id)
```